# string in string, Python 3.7 KeyError

Tags: python

I have stared at this line of code for far too long and I do not understand the exception at all. The line of code is

```python
if '_' in part_word:
```

and the exception is

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'__________n'
  File "C:\Users\timregan\source\pythonlessons\Hangman-Game\Hangman_learn.py", line 50, in play_and_learn
    if '_' in part_word:
  File "C:\Users\timregan\source\pythonlessons\Hangman-Game\Hangman_learn.py", line 66, in main
    play_and_learn()
  File "C:\Users\timregan\source\pythonlessons\Hangman-Game\Hangman_learn.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
```

(N.B. In comments people have asked for more of the code. It is not clear to me which fragment(s) are relevant, so the two Python files are available [here](https://github.com/dumbledad/keyerrorexception/blob/master/Hangman_learn.py), and the problem line is line 50.)

At the point the exception is thrown `part_word` is `'__________n'`. Even stranger is this: a watch in the debugging pane clearly shows that `'_' in part_word` evaluates to `True`.

[image: VSCode screenshot showing watched expression evaluating to True]

The code looks correct—`'_' in part_word` is the correct way to test if the string `part_word` contains the string `'_'`. I can see that it evaluates correctly to `True` in the debugging pane. Any yet it throws a `KeyError` in the main code. Why? How do I diagnose what is going wrong? How might I fix this?

Comment: Can you add some part of the code in the question?

Comment: please provide more code, thx!

Comment: If you've got a `Hangman_learn.pyc` file, delete it. Also, restart Python.

Comment: I've added a link to the source, [here](https://github.com/dumbledad/keyerrorexception/blob/master/Hangman_learn.py) as I am not sure which fragment is relevant (the error is line 50). There is no *.pyc file, and restarting the entire laptop did not fix the issue. I tried changing conda environment too.

Comment: Ted, part_word is a string, it's in the second line of the exception and mentioned explicitly in the question.

Comment: Are you sure the error is not connected with this code: `q_table[part_word]`. It looks like `part_word` is not a key in `q_table`.

Comment: @marcin, you are right, thank you. I've added an answer before I saw your comment, but if you want to make your comment into an answer I'll accept yours.

Comment: No it's ok, accept yours

Answer (score 1):

It's always the way, soon after asking on SO the answer pops into my head!

This still does not quite make sense, but it looks like the error is on the following line, somehow the debugger and the exception text are reporting the wrong line. This is the problem:

```python
max_future_score = max([score for letter, score in q_table[part_word]])
```

because of an earlier mistake, `part_word` is not a key in `q_table`, hence the KeyError. I'm not sure why it is being reported on the previous line by the exception and the debugger.

(N.B. The answer renders the question wrong, it is not a KeyError with string containment, but I'll leave it up just in case anyone else encounters a `KeyError` that actually arises from the following statement.)